# Partial correlation in panda dataframe python

Tags: regression, statsmodels, partial-correlation

I have a data in pandas dataframe like:

```
df = 

    X1  X2  X3  Y
0   1   2   10  5.077
1   2   2   9   32.330
2   3   3   5   65.140
3   4   4   4   47.270
4   5   2   9   80.570
```

and I want to do multiple regression analysis. Here Y is dependent variables and X1, X2 and X3 are independent variables.
correlation between each independent variables with dependent variable is:

```
df.corr():

      X1          X2            X3         Y
X1  1.000000    0.353553    -0.409644   0.896626
X2  0.353553    1.000000    -0.951747   0.204882
X3  -0.409644   -0.951747   1.000000    -0.389641
Y   0.896626    0.204882    -0.389641   1.000000
```

​As we can see here Y has highest correlation with X1 so i have selected X1 as first independent variable. And following the process I am trying to select second independent variable with highest partial correlation with X. So my question is how to find partial correlation in such case?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How exactly would you define what you're trying to find? Would the second independent variable be defined as the one that has the highest correlation with the residual of $y$ regressed on $x1$ (and so forth)?

Comment: @Ami Tavory yes exactly i used the term partial correlation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you what you are asking for:

```
from scipy import stats, linalg

def partial_corr(C):
    """
    Returns the sample linear partial correlation coefficients between pairs of variables in C, controlling 
    for the remaining variables in C.
    Parameters
    ----------
    C : array-like, shape (n, p)
        Array with the different variables. Each column of C is taken as a variable
    Returns
    -------
    P : array-like, shape (p, p)
        P[i, j] contains the partial correlation of C[:, i] and C[:, j] controlling
        for the remaining variables in C.
    """

    C = np.asarray(C)
    p = C.shape[1]
    P_corr = np.zeros((p, p), dtype=np.float)
    for i in range(p):
        P_corr[i, i] = 1
        for j in range(i+1, p):
            idx = np.ones(p, dtype=np.bool)
            idx[i] = False
            idx[j] = False
            beta_i = linalg.lstsq(C[:, idx], C[:, j])[0]
            beta_j = linalg.lstsq(C[:, idx], C[:, i])[0]

            res_j = C[:, j] - C[:, idx].dot( beta_i)
            res_i = C[:, i] - C[:, idx].dot(beta_j)

            corr = stats.pearsonr(res_i, res_j)[0]
            P_corr[i, j] = corr
            P_corr[j, i] = corr

    return P_corr

partial_corr_array = df.as_matrix(columns = ['price', 'sqft_living', 'sqft_living15'])

# Calculate the partial correlation coefficients
partial_corr(partial_corr_array)
```

Comment: Just to mention that `-np.linalg.inv(np.corrcoef(C.T))` will give the same results and it's half-line of code. `C` is defined as in your code. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

AFAIU from your comment, you're talking about [*recursive feature elimination*](http://www.brainvoyager.com/bvqx/doc/UsersGuide/MVPA/RecursiveFeatureElimination.html), specifically, using linear regression. As [described here](http://blog.datadive.net/selecting-good-features-part-iv-stability-selection-rfe-and-everything-side-by-side/):

> Recursive feature elimination is based on the idea to repeatedly construct a model (for example an SVM or a regression model) and choose either the best or worst performing feature (for example based on coefficients), setting the feature aside and then repeating the process with the rest of the features. This process is applied until all features in the dataset are exhausted. Features are then ranked according to when they were eliminated. As such, it is a greedy optimization for finding the best performing subset of features.

For your case, you could do the following with [`sklearn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html):

```py
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

features = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3']
X = df[features]
y = df['Y']

prd = LinearRegression()
rfe = RFE(prd, n_features_to_select=1)
rfe.fit(X, y)
```

You should be able to see the ranks in `rfe.ranking_`.